# Loading a Buffered Image

Tags: path, bufferedimage

I've been trying to figure this out for days.  I am trying to load a buffered image from my res directory.  My folder hierarchy is.

- MainProjectFolder

  - res

    - my image to be loaded
  - src

    - Logic folder

      - loop.java(my class to pass a string to BufferedImageLoader to be loaded)
    - Graphics Folder

      - BufferedImageLoader.java(converts string to bufferedimage)

However I keep getting a input = null error.  How do I point to my image file?

My Loop class

```
BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try{
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/res/sprite_sheet_test.png");

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My BufferedImageLoaderClass

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String path)throws IOException{
    url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
    newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please update the question with the stack trace! Also, are you sure you want to load the image as a file? It's usually easier to place `res/` in class path, and load as a resource (`getClass().getResource(path_without_res_prefix)`). Google or search SO for similar questions.

Comment: I am kind of new to java and still learning the ropes.  I can load the image like you stated. By using url =this.getClass().getResource(path) However, what would I put in the String path to point to my folder containing my image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the folder `res` is defined as a resource folder in your project and put on class path (and indeed, contains the file `sprite_sheet_test.png`), this should work:

```
loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet_test.png");
```

Note the leading `/`, to make sure the image is loaded from the resource root. Without it, the resource would be resolved relative to the package of your `BufferedImageLoader` class.

Comment: That dosent work either the only thing that works is if I declare the absolute path

Comment: @seiko149 If it doesn't work, it's because `res` isn't part of your class path.

Comment: I got it to work in eclipse by adding the resource folder to the class path.  However, when I try to compile it in command line or export to a runnable jar the image dosen't load.  I think i need to do some more research on how to declare paths.  Thanks for your help in getting it to run.

Comment: @seiko149 Good! You're welcome. :-) You need to make that image part of your JAR. And remember that resources are resolved relative to the "root" of the JAR. I think there are some answers for how to achieve this already on StakcOverflow.